# How select rows that have differents column values and share the same column [date value]

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, sql-order-by, having-clause

I am trying to do some combination of rows. My table is like this

```
┌─────────┬────────────────┬────────────────┐
│Machine_N│      Date      │      Action    │
├─────────┼────────────────┼────────────────┤
│      RS1│ 2018-02-08     │        Reading │
│      RS1│ 2018-02-08     │       Referred │
│      RS1│ 2018-02-16     │        Reading │
│      RS2│ 2018-01-31     │        Reading │
│      RS2│ 2018-01-31     │       Referred │
└─────────┴────────────────┴────────────────┘
```

How to select only the Actions where Date is the same so the result set would be :

```
┌─────────┬────────────────┬────────────────┐
│Machine_N│      Date      │      Action    │
├─────────┼────────────────┼────────────────┤
│      RS1│ 2018-02-08     │        Reading │
│      RS1│ 2018-02-08     │       Referred │
│      RS2│ 2018-01-31     │        Reading │
│      RS2│ 2018-01-31     │       Referred │
└─────────┴────────────────┴────────────────┘
```

I tried a having count clause but no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? (SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle etc)

Comment: I'm using SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have no duplicates, you can use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.machine_n = t.machine_n and t2.date = t.date and t2.action <> t.action);
```

Another method uses window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by machine_n, date) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt > 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `subquery` :

```
select * 
from table t
where date = (select top (1) [date] 
              from table 
              where machine_n = t.machine_n 
              group by date
              order by COUNT(1) desc
             );
```

However not most DBMS has TOP clause so, you can use `LIMIT` clause instead

```
select * 
from table t
where date = (select [date] 
              from table 
              where machine_n = t.machine_n 
              group by date
              order by COUNT(1) desc
              LIMIT 1
              );
```